# How do I find a group that does not match a set of accepted phrases

Tags: regex

How can I search the following url for instances of {thing} that are not phrases that I allow?

Test string;

```
https://example.com?good={offer_id}&good2={offer_name}&bad={revenue}&extra=1
```

{offer_id} and {offer_name} should NOT match 
{revenue} should match

The closest pattern I came up with is (but no matches);

```
/{(?!(offer_id|offer_name))}/
```

In online regex tester: https://regex101.com/r/HwSknv/1

EDIT1: I want to match each instance of {revenue} (or similar).  As I intended to replace them out.

Comment: What exactly you want to do ? Match whole URL if {revenue} is present ?

Comment: I want to match each instance of {revenue} (or similar)

Comment: So you mean content of `bad=` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that you are matching `}` without matching any character after `{`.

You should use:

```
{(?!(?:offer_id|offer_name)})[^}]*}
```

[Updated Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/HwSknv/3)

`[^}]*` will match 0 or more of any character that is not `}` before matching `}`.

Answer (score 0):

`{(?!(offer_id|offer_name)).*?}`

Comment: Unfortunately, this allows stuff like {offer_name£%5646} to slip through.